# How do I backup my Synology NAS to an an expansion unit to carry offsite?

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, synology, offsite-backup

My intent is to use an expansion unit (DX517) to backup my DS920+ NAS, say every week, and then carry it offsite. I hope I bought the right equipment!

I'm an absolute novice at this. All I've done so far is create a new storage pool on the expansion unit and I don't know what to do next. Further, when creating the storage pool I was warned that I can't turn off the expansion unit using the power button, so I don't even know how to actually power it down to carry it offsite once a backup completes. The articles at Synology.com only seem to refer to a USB connected drive.

Another open question: do I have the option of keeping a history of backup snapshots on the expansion unit or do I just get a synced copy of what's on the NAS pool?

Here's my equipment:

DS920+ DSM 7.0.1 (Storage Pool 1, Volume 1) SHR 4x8TB WD Red Plus

DX517 (Storage Pool 2, ) SHR 4x14TB Ironwolf Pro

Can anyone give an outline of my next steps?

Comment: look into the options afaik is there a schedule for copy all

Comment: Thanks @djdomi, I don't see it yet. It may be that I don't have the right package installed to do what I want. Do I need to install "Hyper Backup" or some such?

Comment: taje alook here https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/How_to_back_up_data_from_one_Synology_NAS_to_another_Synology_NAS_for_DSM_4.x_and_DSM_5.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

- I returned the DX517 expansion unit because it couldn't be powered down (to carry offsite) without powering down the NAS. I didn't want that restriction.
- I bought a second NAS (another DS920+ but that's likely overkill) installing the disks from the expansion unit and wiping them.
- Then I installed "Snapshot Replication" on both NASs. And set up a replication task to create snapshots of the original NAS on the second NAS over the LAN.
- The second NAS can now be powered down independent of the first. Further, I'm told that I can move the second NAS to a remote site and plug it into the net and leave it there to create snapshots. This would involve some DNS, VPN, firewall stuff that I haven't tried to figure out. But it is an advertised feature of these Synology products.

Hope this helps others.